# XLConnect disabling vlookup

Tags: xlconnect

I am using XLConnect to copy monthly data to a template. The template has vlookups and I can get the new data to the new template file no problem. THe problem is in excel the new template now with the new data the vlookups don't recognize the data until I manually click each cell and the formula bar then it recognizes the data.

I have tried changing the formula to automatic but that still doesn't work. Anyone seen this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out

setForceFormulaRecalculation(wb, sheet = 1, TRUE)

here is an example
https://rdrr.io/cran/XLConnect/man/setForceFormulaRecalculation-methods.html